# Отображение и хранение формул в C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Делаю программу для тестирования школьников. При создании теста необходимо, чтобы у учителя была возможность вставить формулу в вопрос (например, при создании теста по математике чтобы можно было нарисовать дробь, а не использовать знак / или нарисовать степень, а не использовать знак ^). Стандартное текстовое поле, как мне кажется, не подойдет. Какие способы существуют для решения подобного рода задач в С#? Эти формулы необходимо ведь еще как-то хранить, и, как я понимаю, это, наверное, будет не простой .txt-файл.

Comment: Сразу вопрос: почему не применять картинки?

Comment: Например, есть [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/), который рендерит TeX-овские формулы (знаете?) в браузере (вы можете попробовать его на [math.hashcode](http://math.hashcode.ru)). Попробуйте поискать библиотеку, которая делала бы то же самое в C#.

Comment: Adam скажите какой метод отображения формул вы выбрали?

Answer (score 1):

Приходят на ум четыре способа:

1. Выводить формулы картинками. Это проще всего, но картинки должны быть сформированы заранее, т.е. подстановку чисел в формулу сделать не получится.
2. Можно загружать картинки с сервиса http://www.codecogs.com/eqnedit.php, который принимает формулы в формате LaTeX и рендерит из них изображения в заданном формате. Формулы можно делать в коде и налету запрашивать картинки у сервиса.
3. Формировать формулы в формате MathML и отображать их в browser control, размещенном на форме. Здесь есть один нюанс, описанный на [StackOwerflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523380/how-do-i-render-an-equation-from-math-input-panel-in-a-wpf-app-and-use-mathml-in). IE не имеет встроенной поддержки MathML, но это решается установкой [MathPlayer](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathplayer/download.htm). Таким образом можно налету формировать формулы и отображать их в browser control, а стилизовать с использованием CSS. (Как это запустить, не представляю, но копать, видимо, здесь...)
4. Сформировать html, который разместить в browser control, но для рендеринга использовать библиотеку скриптов [mathjax](http://www.mathjax.org/).

Дополнение

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899204/how-to-render-a-formula-in-wpf-or-winforms) нашли решение проблемы. [Здесь](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11406/Enable-Your-Users-to-Write-Math-Equations-in-Your) описание, как генерить картинки для настольного приложения.